# Load Freebase using python

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, word2vec, freebase

I got  freebase-vectors-skipgram1000-en.bin.gz
 from https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/
Then rename it to 
 freebase-vectors-skipgram1000-en.bin
 and used it in my code

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec
gvc='freebase-vectors-skipgram1000-en.bin'
model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(gvc,binary=True)
```

It gives me this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I will be grateful for any help regarding this issue.

Comment: Renaming a compressed `.gz` file, to another name without the `.gz` (but still compressed), will often confuse tools which use the filename as a hint of the file format. Either leave the file with its original name, or truly uncompress it, and your load should work. (Gensim can read the compressed `.gz` file, too!)

Comment: i used .gz now it gives me this:array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: You might possibly find a command like `/usr/bin/split -l 100` to be helpful. But most likely, as Roy Scheider's character announced, You're gonna need a bigger boat! Obtaining a host with more memory would be appropriate.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you may need more RAM. (Even if you could use virtual memory, the typical `most_similar()` operations on these models touch every element, to find the top-N results, meaning any swapping is disastrous for performance.) Also, if you're using a 32-bit Python executable (sometimes still a problem on Windows), you could be hitting array-size implementation limits.

Comment: In the meantime, `load_word2vec_format()` also has an optional `limit` argument for just reading the 1st `limit` entries. As word-vectors are typically stored with most-frequent words 1st, and the long tail of less-frequent words tend to be both poorer-quality & less important to many applications, you may find that just loading the 1st 50K words (`limit=50000`), or 100K, etc, works OK for your needs in a smaller amount of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than renaming what you downloaded, use this to properly unpack it:

```
$ gunzip -v freebase-vectors-skipgram1000-en.bin.gz
```